# 做工作 or 要工作？What is the difference here?

Tags: word-choice

[image]
From the statement, it looks like this man tries to bribe the refree. So he offers a job to a refree to help him win a game. Isn't it 找裁判要工作? He wants the job done by a refree?

Answer (score 2):

做工作 is a fixed phrase meaning to persuade someone to agree or side with you. It is shortened from 做思想工作, "to do ideological job", while 思想工作 is a political term referring to the task of disseminating the party's stance.

Hence, 做思想工作 is to make someone side with the party, and gradually its sense has been generalized to "to make someone side with you". Here, to bribe the referee so he sides with Li Tie, i.e. to give Li unfair advantage.